# Changing the type of the Response in a Call object

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm consuming an API endpoint with Retrofit 2, and I would like to mutate the response object type in a `Call` object.  I need to use a `Call` object so that I can cancel the request.

This behavior is easy with rxJava.  For instance, let's say I have an endpoint that returns an Account object, but I'd like to return the an Email object instead.  With rxJava I can do something like:

```
public Observable<Email> getEmail(Account account) {

    return service.getUser().map(new Func1<Account, Email>() {
        @Override public Email call(Account account) {

            return new Email(account.getEmail());
        }
    });
}
```

where `getUser()` returns and `Observable<Account>`.

However, `call.enqueue` does not seem to allow this kind of chaining.  Is there a way to accomplish the above with a `Call<Email>` instead of rxJava to allow request cancellation?

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to do it in retrofit. But you can use `Response<JsonElement>` and get as Json object your response and after that use any json deserializer to convert to your class.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
            JsonObject objectWhichYouNeed = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

            //use any json deserializer to convert to your class.
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(response.message());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }
});
```